# How can I add a CSS spinner to a Clickdimensions submit button?

Tags: javascript, css, spinner

I am using ClickDimensions Widget to populate a form on our upcoming WP website.
The form is built using clickdimensions form designer, which allows to add additional JS and CSS.

I would like to attach a spinner to the submit button, which would be triggered on submit.
This method fails. The form posts but no spinner appears.

here is the code I have implemented:

```html
// Select the parent container and the input by their class and id
const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('.buttonContainer');

// Create a new spinner element
const spinner = document.createElement('span');

// Add the spinner class to the span
spinner.className = 'spinner';

// Append the spinner to the parent container
buttonContainer.appendChild(spinner);

// Attach a submit event listener to the form

document.getElementById('clickdimensionsForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
  // Display spinner
    spinner.style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

What could be the issue?
Is there a way around it?

Comment: unfortunately, it posts the form anyway. even with the preventDefault call.

Comment: I have no access to the async function clickdimensions is pushing to the page. I can only try to create a additional function that will trigger the spinner. but the async function is posting before my function can trigger.

Comment: I added it in an additional function which can be done within the dorm designer of Clickdimensions. but it looks like that function does not get called on time. the async comes first. do you actually know how Clickdimensions work or are you just trolling?

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea "clickdimensions" was something *special* - to be honest, it didn't even occur to me what you meant by "a WP website" - comments removed so as not to upset you

Comment: thank you. WP as Wordpress. I also should have specified. clickdimensions is the Microsoft answer to Salesforce Pardot.